# execute a .jar file from C# but it generates files at wrong location

Tags: java, c#, jar

I have coded a Minecraft Server Runner in C# WinForms which lets you run a Minecraft Server, a .jar file which needs to generate files. The problem is that I launch this .jar file via the .exe application, and the files generate at the .exe application location.

-- What I have tried:

I tried moving the .exe application to the specific server file location, but the application needs a restart to register this change which I don't want to happen.

I also don't want the user being forced to put the .exe application to the Server folder and restart it. Here is the code I use to launch the .jar file:

```
Process.Start("C:\user\documents\server\server.jar");
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I executed the .jar file in the C# application via the CMD.
Here is the code I used instead:

```
string path = @"C:\user\documents\server\"; //Path to your server.jar file.
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = path + "server.jar"; //Name of the .jar file.
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = path;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
process.Start();
```

All credits go to "Olivier Rogier" ( https://stackoverflow.com/users/12031933/olivier-rogier ) for helping me find this solution

Answer (score 1):

The jar file can be executed by the `java -jar filename.jar`. So use the following [Process.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netcore-3.1#System_Diagnostics_Process_Start_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Security_SecureString_System_String_) call to invoke the jar.

```
Process.Start("java", "-jar C:\user\documents\server\server.jar", username, password, domain);
```

Hope this helps.

**P.S: For this to work, either add the Java to your path or invoke with the java.exe's Path.**